# PHP Composer require dependency if *condition*

Tags: composer-php

Is there any way to require a dependency in `composer.json` only if a condition is fulfilled?

Typically, I'd like to use Guzzle 6 if the PHP version is high enough, otherwise do nothing. The library will handle a fallback if you don't have guzzle.

I know you can use `"some/dependency": "^1.0 || ^2.0"`, which will choose the latest major that fits your other requirements. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
"some/dependency": "nothing || ^2.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly as constraints in your `composer.json`. However you can achieve this by creating bridge package, which may define different dependencies for different versions, which could have different requirements.

So you can create `me/guzzle-wrapper` package and:

1. Tag `1.0.0` version with `composer.json`:

   ```
   {
       "name": "me/guzzle-wrapper",
       "require": {
           "php": "<5.5",
       }
   }
   ```
2. Tag `2.0.0` version with `composer.json`:

   ```
   {
       "name": "me/guzzle-wrapper",
       "require": {
           "php": ">=5.5",
           "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
       }
   }
   ```

So instead requiring `guzzlehttp/guzzle` directly, you can use this meta package - depending on your PHP version Composer will install `2.0.0` which requires Guzzle, or `1.0.0` which does not require anything.

But if your package is able to work without Guzzle, maybe you should move this requirement to `suggest` section?

Comment: I think it's a good solution  I'd rather keep everything in one repository but I'll think about it. At first, I thought about having 2 separate package and requiring a virtual package (like httplug does) but it felt very over engineered ^^
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, Jordi (maker of composer) confrmed over email that this would be the best solution 